# Python Conditional XML Writing

Tags: python, xml

I am using Python to convert CSV files to XML format. The CSV files have a varying amount of rows ranging anywhere from 2 (including headers) to infinity. (realistically 10-15 but unless there's some major performance issue, I'd like to cover my bases) In order to convert the files I have the following code:

```py
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        xmlData.write('    <'+csvFile[:-4]+'-1>' + "\n")
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    if rowNum == 1: 
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
        xmlData.write('    </'+csvFile[:-4]+'-1>' + "\n" + '    <' +csvFile[:-4]+'-2>' + "\n")
    if rowNum == 2:
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
        xmlData.write('    </'+csvFile[:-4]+'-2>' + "\n")
    if rowNum == 3:
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('<'+csvFile[:-4]+'-3>' + "\n" + '        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
        xmlData.write('    </'+csvFile[:-4]+'-3>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1
xmlData.write('</csv_data>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

As you can see, I have the upper-level tags set to be created manually if the row exists. Is there a more efficient way to achieve my goal of creating the `<csvFile-*></csvFile-*>` tags rather than repeating my code 15+ times? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml.etree](http://lxml.de/) to write the XML. xml.etree.ElementTree is in the standard library, but does not have built-in pretty-printing. (You could use the indent function from [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint), however).

lxml.etree is a third-party module, but it has built-in pretty-printing in its `tostring` method.

Using lxml.etree, you could do something like this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

csvData = [['foo bar', 'baz quux'],['bing bang', 'bim bop', 'bip burp'],]
csvFile = 'rowboat'
name = csvFile[:-4]
root = ET.Element('csv_data')
for num, tags in enumerate(csvData):
    row = ET.SubElement(root, '{f}-{n}'.format(f = name, n = num))
    for text in tags:
        text = text.replace(' ', '_')
        tag = ET.SubElement(row, text)
        tag.text = text

print(ET.tostring(root, pretty_print = True))
```

yields

```
<csv_data>
  <row-0>
    <foo_bar>foo_bar</foo_bar>
    <baz_quux>baz_quux</baz_quux>
  </row-0>
  <row-1>
    <bing_bang>bing_bang</bing_bang>
    <bim_bop>bim_bop</bim_bop>
    <bip_burp>bip_burp</bip_burp>
  </row-1>
</csv_data>
```

---

Some suggestions:

- In Python, almost never do you need to say

  ```
  for i in range(len(tags)):
      # do stuff with tags[i]
  ```

  Instead say

  ```
  for tag in tags:
  ```

  to loop over all the items in `tags`.
- Also instead of manually counting the times through a loop with

  ```
  num = 0
  for tags in csvData:
      num += 1
  ```

  instead use the [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

  ```
  for num, tags in enumerate(csvData):
  ```
- Strings like

  ```
  '        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                           + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n"
  ```

  are incredibly difficult to read. It mixes together logic of
  indentation, with the XML syntax of tags, with the minutia of end of
  line characters. That's where `xml.etree.ElementTree` or `lxml.etree`
  will help you. It will take care of the serialization of the XML for
  you; all you need to provide is the relationship between the XML elements.
  The code will be much more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Great response, thank you! My code is getting cleaner by the minute!